# Ordering of cholim in bracha r'fayeinu

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shemoneh-esrei, choleh-sick, kerovim-close-relatives

In shemoneh esrei, if adding in names of cholim in the bracha of r'fayeinu, is there a preferred ordering when mentioning multiple cholim by name?

Some possibilities I thought of:

1. doesn't matter
2. men first, then women (as some shuls do by the misheberach for cholim in krias haTorah)
3. kerovim (relatives) first, then doesn't matter, such as parents, siblings, then others
4. most recent addition to the list first
5. least recent addition to the list first
6. in degree of presumed sakana the choleh is in ("deathbed" vs ongoing but serious illness)